# meaning of before widget and after widget

Tags: wordpress

I want to know what is meaning of `before widget` and `after widget` in the following code:

```
register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Primary Sidebar', 'twentyfourteen' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => __( 'Main sidebar that appears on the left.', 'twentyfourteen' ),
        **'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',**
        'before_title'  => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h1>',
```

Answer (score 1):

Meaning :

before_widget - HTML to place before every widget(default:`'<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">'`) Note: uses sprintf for variable substitution

after_widget - HTML to place after every widget (default: `"</li>\n"`).

Before widget output place before widget execution and After widget output place after widget execution

For more info [Visit this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar).